# determine whether the sequence $f_{n}(x) = x^n - x^{n+1}$ converges uniformly on the set [0,1]

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Determine whether the sequence $f_{n}(x) = x^n - x^{n+1}$ converges uniformly on the set [0,1].

**My trial:**

I took the limit as n tends to $\infty$ and I can see that this function converges pointwisely to 0, but then how can I find N such that regardless of x, $|x^n - x^{n+1}| < \epsilon$, could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call $g_n(x)=x^n-x^{n+1}=x^n(1-x)$, then (at least for $n\ge 2$) $g'_n(x)=nx^{n-1}-(n+1)x^n=x^{n-1}(n-(n+1)x)=0$ $\iff$ $x=0$ or $x_n=\frac{n}{n+1}$.

It is not difficult to see that $x_n$ is maximum. so $$\sup|x^n-x^{n+1}|=g_n(x_n)= \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n}\cdot \frac{1}{n+1}\to(bounded)\cdot 0=0 $$

So you have uniform convergence to the null function.

Comment: No, you fixed it after the edit. I upvoted your answer.

Comment: I did not understand why you set the derivative to be zero?

Comment: @hopefully in order to calculate the supremum over $[0,1]$, or equivalently, the maximum over $[0,1]$. REcall that $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $A$ $\iff$ $\sup_A|f_n-f|\to 0$.

Comment: How can I prove that $(n/(n+1))^n$ is bounded ...... I know why it is bounded as the amount inside () is always less than 1 .... but how I can prove this?

Comment: @hopefully Because the function $f(x)=x^n$ is strictly increeasing on $[0,+\infty)$ for any $n\in\mathbb N$ (in fact, this is true for $f(x)=x^c$ for any $c>0$).

Comment: if $x \in (0,1)$ then $x^n$ is not increasing.